# Knockout - Binding on an input select produces option tags with empty values

Tags: knockout.js

I have this HTML tag using Knockout:

```
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', value: 'id', event: { change: selectItems }"></select>
```

and this function for the change event:

```
self.selectItems = function (context, event) {
    // do something with selected value here
};
```

I was expecting to get the value of id in event.target.value but it is empty. Upon checking the inner html, I found out that the generated options, they are all empty:

```
<option value="">All Items</option>
<option value="">Bag</option>
// more
```

I've confirmed that the id have values in the viewModel. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Change will pass the current context into the method as context so context.id() will give you the current value. id will be set to the selected item in the items array. Is that what you want? Otherwise you should also use optionsValue: 'id' to set id to id of the selected item

Comment: @Wayne Ellery: Thanks, looks like I needed to use optionsValue, just as you said. Could you put this in an answer so I could mark it as the answer? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have used the `value` binding without the `optionsValue` binding then `id` will be set to the selected option object from the items array. I think you meant to set id to the id of the selected option object so you should use `optionsValue='id'`.

```
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue='id', value: 'id', event: { change: selectItems }"></select>
```

Then to access the the selected id you can use:

```
self.selectItems = function (context, event) {
    console.debug(context.id());
};
```